# How to add new tag in xml structure payload using MEL (mule)

Tags: mule, mule-el

I'm new to Mule, please guide me how to insert new tag inside the XML structure using Mule Expression Language (MEL).Need to insert B  tag in the below XML structure

```
<Test>
<A>table 1</A>
<C>table 3</C>
</Test>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My dom4j fu is limited but here is what I came up with:

```
<mulexml:xml-to-dom-transformer returnClass="org.dom4j.Document" />

<expression-component><![CDATA[
  bNode = message.payload.rootElement.addElement('B');
  bNode.text = 'table 2';
  message.payload.rootElement.elements().add(1, bNode.detach());
]]></expression-component>

<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer />
```

This works fine with Mule 3.4.0.

Comment: Thanks David.It is workig fine for me.Kindly help me in understanding which script is used here in manipulating rootElement,addElement(),elements().add().Also referred XML DOM in W3schools,but unable to correlate both.Kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Data Weave component as below:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%var myValue='MyValue'
%var B=''
---

myoutput:{
    data: payload.Test ++ B:myValue

}
```